# ANTLR4 parsing a Wiktionary article fails weirdly

Tags: parsing, antlr, mediawiki, antlr4, text-parsing

I'm trying to parse mediawiki markup, specifically the one used in english wiktionary articles.
It not being a programming language, the handling of whitespace and newlines is kind of weird, plus I feel like every step is trial and (lots of) error.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/WorDB/wikitext-parser

The test input file is the *pie* article: [pie.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WorDB/wikitext-parser/master/data/pie.txt)
(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pie)

**Note**: I'm parsing the whole XML dump of wiktionary, so I'd rather find a solution parsing with Antlr and not get suggestions like using some online API.

`wikitext.g4`

```
grammar wikitext;

/**
 Grammar
 */

page: EOL? ((wikitem | bullet_line) EOL? )+ EOF;

wikitem:
      wikitem wikitem
    | title 
    | template
    | link
    | text
    ;

title: title2 | title3 | title4 | title5;
title5: '=====' text '=====';
title4: '====' text '====';
title3: '===' text '===';
title2: '==' text '==';

template: '{{' parameter ('|' parameter)* '}}';
link: '[[' parameter ('|' parameter)* ']]';

parameter: wikitem?; // parameter can be empty, I.E. {{a|}}

bullet: ('*'|'#'|'#:'|'#*');
bullet_line: WS? EOL WS? bullet WS? wikitem;

text: (CHAR | WS)+;

/**
 Lexicon
 */
EOL: [\f\r\n]+;
CHAR: ~[ \t\f\r\n];
WS: [ \t]+;
```

`Error:`

```
> cd ./java && grun wikitext page -gui ../data/pie.txt

line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'rom {{inh|en|enm|pye}}, from {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'om {{inh|en|enm|pye}}, from {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'm {{inh|en|enm|pye}}, from {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' {{inh|en|enm|pye}}, from {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' from {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'from {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'rom {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'om {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'm {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' {{der|en|fro|pie}}, from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'from {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'rom {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'om {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'm {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' {{der|en|la|pīca}}, feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'feminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'eminine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'minine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'inine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'nine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'ine of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'ne of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'e of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'of {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'f {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' {{m|la|pīcus||woodpecker}}, from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'from {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'rom {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'om {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input 'm {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 no viable alternative at input ' {{der|en|ine-pro|*'
line 190:137 extraneous input '*' expecting {'|', '}}'}
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input 's)peyk-|'
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input ')peyk-|'
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input 'peyk-|'
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input 'eyk-|'
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input 'yk-|'
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input 'k-|'
line 190:146 no viable alternative at input '-|'
line 190:146 mismatched input '|' expecting {<EOF>, '=====', '====', '===', '==', '{{', '[[', EOL, CHAR, WS}
```

Comment: In Antlr, the lexer runs independently of the parser; there is no context-sensitive lexing. '{{' is returned by the lexer, but the parser rule `text: (CHAR | WS)+;` does not accept '{{' in line 190. You either need to list all multi-character tokens in the parser rule, or break up your string literals into a sequence of individual characters.

Comment: There are other options than writing your own grammar or using an API. Writing your own ANTLR grammar is not an easy task for a markup language like Mediawiki (a PEG would be a more natural candidate, if you want to do it yourself). But I'd look for an existing parser: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsing

Comment: Someone already tried writing a grammar (using ANTLR3): https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Markup_spec/ANTLR/draft . Looking at the grammar, I'm guessing this did not go well: it's quite a mess with so many predicates (containing target specific code), global backtracking turned on. Again: try to find an existing parser for this.

Comment: @kaby76 It's ok, I don't want _{{_ parsed as text but as template. But neither happens.

Comment: @BartKiers yes, I've read that and many other pages and projects, Parsoid, for example made a cumbersome switch from JS to PHP, I've done the inverse path after 20 years and not going back.
Anyway, when install instructions and dependencies are too complex and bug reports are many, I prefer to spend my time rolling one out myself, time during which I learn as a plus. But thanks, I may reconsider revisiting PHP with parsoid.

Comment: No problemo @Petruza. Best of luck with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed some rules. Could you check it?

```
grammar wikitext;

/**
 Grammar
 */

page: EOL? (wikitem EOL? )+ EOF;

wikitem:
      wikitem wikitem
    | title
    | template
    | link
    | text
    | bullet_line
    ;

title: title2 | title3 | title4 | title5;
title5: '=====' text '=====';
title4: '====' text '====';
title3: '===' text '===';
title2: '==' text '==';

template: '{{' parameter ('|' parameter)* '}}';
link: '[[' parameter ('|' parameter)* ']]';

parameter: wikitem?; // parameter can be empty, I.E. {{a|}}

bullet_line: WS? bullet=('*'|'#'|'#:'|'#*') WS? wikitem;

text: (CHAR | WS)+;

/**
 Lexicon
 */
EOL: [\f\r\n]+;
CHAR: ~[ \t\f\r\n];
WS: [ \t]+;
```

Comment: Thanks! it did work pretty well. Now I need to handle newlines inside some _wikitems_ like _templates_ which can have many parameters in different lines.